# Suddenly cannot ssh to ec2 isntance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-code-deploy

I've been able to ssh into my instance for  a long while.
Just recently, I've created a copy of my instance through an AMI in order to move over to code pipeline.
My new instance used the same key pair and I was able to ssh to it in the beginning.
Suddenly in middle of working today, I was not able to ssh into it anymore.
I verified that my key pair is good, the IP is good, the instance is running properly, and that my security group is allowing all traffic, but nothing helped.
I've tried creating an AMI and making a new instance from it using a new key pair but had the same issue.
I've tried mounting the storage of the instance to another working instance to see the contents of .ssh/authorized_keys and everything looks good there.
Can anyone please help me figure out why I can't access my instance anymore???

Additionally, I had the same story a few days again with another instance (i-036dfa448ef7cc321). Two days after setting up the Codedeploy pipeline, I suddenly couldn't ssh to it anymore. I thought it was a one-time glitch, but now it happened to our production instance.

Comment: What error do yout get? Have you checked ssh logs what error do you get?

Comment: Use `ssh -vvv ...` to create a debug log and add it to your Question. Does `Get System Log` look normal?

Comment: You might be able to login with AWS Systems Manager Session Manager if the right permissions are assigned to the instance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer from AWS support. The issue was that I set wrong permissions on certain folders. Below is instructions on how to resolve:

Steps :-

---

- Open the Amazon EC2 console -> Stop your instance.
- Choose Actions, choose Instance Settings, and then choose Edit User Data.
- Copy your user script into the Edit user data box, and then choose Save.

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type:
    text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
OS_USER=ec2-user
chown root:root /home
chmod 755 /home
chown $OS_USER:$OS_USER/home/$OS_USER -R
chmod 700 /home/$OS_USER
chmod 700 /home/$OS_USER/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/$OS_USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
--//

~~~~~~~~~~~Do not include these lines~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks!!
I had the same issue, and it was because I opened too much (777) the permissions of /home/ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is that I copied & pasted the Public IPv4 address from my aws ec2 instance again on the ssh connect script & that worked (e.g. `ssh -i yourKeyPairFile yourInstanceType@yourPublicIPv4Address`), whereas before it was hanging & then getting connection timed out.

I had also previously stopped & started my instance, & rebooted so maybe it didn't want to connect anymore because I did not gracefully exit the instance like with `sudo shutdown -h now`.